# How to find one private key from the list of 15 million public keys for the sake of experimentation?

Tags: private-key, public-key, attack, key-collision, hack

Recently found a list of compressed public keys. The total number of **15 000 000 public keys**.
Practical for all compressed public keys **Balance: 0.000100 BTC**

I do not set malicious goals. All just for the sake of interest and sports experiment I would like to try to find at least one private key from this entire list?
For the most part, I want to understand, apart from **"Brute Force"** **(which will not help)**, are there more promising methods and ways of finding a private key?

Is it possible to search for a private key? Or are there some mathematical attacks, even when you know a large number of public keys?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I need to recover private key?,](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/84215/i-need-to-recover-private-key)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Wallet gone and lost recovery phrase, how to get back my bitcoins?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/64446/wallet-gone-and-lost-recovery-phrase-how-to-get-back-my-bitcoins)

Answer (score 1):

That's how crypto works where public key cannot retrieve private key. If you were able to retrieve the private key with public key then bitcoin would be at high risk.

The only way is to `Brute Force (Nearly impossible)` or `Social Engineering (Only if you know who owns the key)` or Somewhere that stores leaked private key otherwise, you just can't obtain it.

Comment: It does not help if I even know a large number of public keys?

Comment: Nope, each different public key has it own private key so it won't help.

Comment: And such Entropy Attacks can give something useful with a large number of public keys? https://blog.cr.yp.to/20140205-entropy.html

Comment: but you do not know how those key are generated though.

It might be generated using a very secure environment with a lot of randomnesses or it might not.

Comment: Yes, that's right about the private keys from the list, I know almost nothing.