# Exodus import from computer to computer

Tags: wallet-import, exodus

I got my

> seco

files but if there is encrypted how am I supposed to read them.

Answer (score 0):

If data in the files are encrypted, you are supposed to read them by running the Exodus application and giving it the passphrase when it asks for it. The software then uses the passphrase as a decryption key, or to produce one.

Alternatively you should be able to recreate the wallet from the recovery phrase you wrote down when you first created the wallet.

Related :

- [I have lost my wallet, what can I do?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/103688/13866)
- [Wallet gone and lost recovery phrase, how to get back my bitcoins?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/64446/13866)